# Xfce notification for detected keyboard and/or mouse

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, notification, kvm-switch

I have a 4-port KM switch (4 screens, 4 computers, 1 keyboard and mouse switched across all of them).

I was wondering if there was some sort of notification tool to display a popup in Xfce (Xubuntu) when it detects the keyboard and/or mouse is plugged in.

Alternatively, is there a console app or command to trigger a notification in Xfce so I could perform a `tail -f /var/log/syslog` and based on the results of that display a notification?

I currently have the KM switch behind my desk so I can't see the lights and this tool would just be an added convenience.  The idea is, each computer would show a notification popup when the keyboard/mouse is detected on that machine (I still need to figure out how to do this in Windows - another question, another stackexchange).

Definitely a first-world problem, and no big deal - just curious.

Thanks

Comment: This should lead you to your goal: `watch 'tail -n1 /var/log/syslog | xargs notify-send'`:p

Answer (score 0):

I did a bit of digging around and based on the `notify-send` command (thanks mreq for that) and the `swatch` command, I came up with this:

```
swatch --config-file=/etc/swatch.conf --tail-file=/var/log/syslog
```

And my swatch.conf looks like this:

```
# Watch log file for word "Comfort" (Comfort Mouse, maybe be more specific)
# Don't trigger more than 1 notification in 5 seconds.
watchfor /Comfort/
    echo
    exec notify-send -t 3000 "Keyboard / Mouse Detected" "$_"
    threshold track_by=$1, type=limit, count=1, seconds=5
```

Now I just gotta toss a --daemon on the end of the command and create an init script and I should be good to go I think.

Btw, `notify-send` can be added by running `sudo apt-get install libnotify-bin`

Thank you!